# How to use Remember me in spring security for custom authentication

Tags: cookies, spring-security, session-cookies, remember-me

Can any one give me idea how to use Remember me check box in spring security for custom authentication,

this is my remember me field in login page

and this is the configuration in secuirty.xml

thanks

Answer (score 2):

As defined in [Spring Docs](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/springsecurity-single.html#nsa-remember-me), when one declares a "remember-me", the "user-service-ref" should be:

> "The remember-me services implementations require access to a
>   UserDetailsService, so there has to be one defined in the application
>   context."

However, in your case, your user-service-ref is a ref to a bean of type MyCustomAuthentication. This is why you get the ClassCastException "MyCustomAuthentication cannot be cast to UserDetailsService".

You should define something like:

```
<security:user-service id="userDetailsService">
    <security:user name="username" password="pass" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
</security:user-service>
```

and use this id in the "user-service-ref"

P.S. IMHO you will have to fix your authentication-provider as well

HTH

For your request, to be more precise:

```
        <http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
             ...    
             <remember-me  user-service-ref="customUserDetailsManager"/>
        </http>




        <b:bean id="customUserDetailsManager"
            class="com.something.something.MyCustomUserDetailsManager" />

        <authentication-manager>
            <authentication-provider user-service-ref="customUserDetailsManager">
            </authentication-provider>

        </authentication-manager>



    </b:beans>
```

Note that MyCustomUserDetailsManager should implement UserDetailsManager

Another important note (from the docs):

> Note that both (Spring's) implemementations require a
>   UserDetailsService. If you are using an authentication provider which
>   doesn't use a UserDetailsService (for example, the LDAP provider) then
>   it won't work unless you also have a UserDetailsService bean in your
>   application context.

Comment: you can still use your custom authentication class. yet you MUST define userDetailsService , and ref it to the places as I showed you, otherwise you will keep getting exceptions from spring.

Comment: I've added an exmaple, see above. Be kind and mark this answer as helpful, if it is.

Comment: the remember-me has nothing to do with the Authentication-Provider. Sure you can implement your own provider, and THEN you use <authentication-provider ref="customAuthProvider">. and the remember-me stays the same as I showed in the example.

Comment: I believe that reading a bit more in the documentations will help. Try this: http://static.springsource.org/spring-http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/springsecurity-single.html#remember-me

Comment: No problem. I've added (in my answer here) another important and relevant quote from the docs, about the need in userDetailsService. You MUST have userDetailsService in your XML, otherwise the remember-me will not work.